# BufferedOutputStream writing garbage data

Tags: java, servlets, download, stream

I am writing download servlet that reads a html file and writes to `servletOutputStream`, the problem right at the of the file transferred it is adding some garbage data any suggestions about this,

below is code I am using for this

---

```
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;
        servOut   = response.getOutputStream();
        bos       = new BufferedOutputStream(servOut);
        fileObj = new File(file);
        fileToDownload = new FileInputStream(fileObj);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fileToDownload);
        response.setContentType("application/text/html");
          response.setHeader("ContentDisposition","attachment;filename="+dump+".html");
        byte[] barray = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bis.read(barray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            bos.write(barray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        }
        bos.flush();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bis.read` returns the number of bytes read. You need to take that into account in your `write` call.

Something like:

```
int rd;
while ((rd=bis.read(...)) != -1) {
     bos.write(..., rd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the following part of your code:

```
        while ((bis.read(barray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            bos.write(barray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        }
```

You are always writing out a multiple of `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes, **even if the size of your input isn't a multiple of `BUFFER_SIZE`**. This results in garbage being written at the end of the last block.

You can fix it like so:

```
        int read;
        while ((read = bis.read(barray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            bos.write(barray, 0, read);
        }
```

Comment: If you find this answer as solution.. Mark It Correct.